# add symbol % to all the data frame in R

Tags: r, string, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have a dataset like `mt.per <- head(mtcars)` and I want to add `%` at the end of each cell value in all the dataset. many thanks in advance
expected answer

```
                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
    Mazda RX4         21.0%   6% 160% 110 % 3.90% 2.620% 16.46%  0%  1%    4% 4%
    Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0%   6%  160% 110% 3.90% 2.875% 17.02%  0%  1%    4% 4%
..... and so on
```

Comment: Another option: `mt.per[] <- paste0(unlist(mt.per), "%")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work, using base R:

```
mt.per <- head(mtcars)
mt.per[] <- lapply(mt.per, function(x) paste0(x,'%'))
mt.per
                    mpg cyl disp   hp  drat     wt   qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21%  6% 160% 110%  3.9%  2.62% 16.46% 0% 1%   4%   4%
Mazda RX4 Wag       21%  6% 160% 110%  3.9% 2.875% 17.02% 0% 1%   4%   4%
Datsun 710        22.8%  4% 108%  93% 3.85%  2.32% 18.61% 1% 1%   4%   1%
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4%  6% 258% 110% 3.08% 3.215% 19.44% 1% 0%   3%   1%
Hornet Sportabout 18.7%  8% 360% 175% 3.15%  3.44% 17.02% 0% 0%   3%   2%
Valiant           18.1%  6% 225% 105% 2.76%  3.46% 20.22% 1% 0%   3%   1%
>
```

Comment: No anonymous function needed `lapply(mt.per, paste0, "%")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below. `apply` allows you to avoid loops and setting its `MARGIN` parameter to `2` will apply the function defined to every column (represented as `x` within `apply`). Since `paste` is vectorized, each individual elements will be pasted within the column.

```
mt.per <- head(mtcars)
res <- apply(mt.per, 2 , function(x) paste0(x,'%'))
```

Comment: This is less nice than the other solutions because `apply` converts to matrix and returns a `matrix` class result instead of a data frame. I'd prefer the `lapply` solution for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple `dplyr` solution:

```
mt.per %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~paste0(., "%")))
```

Answer (score 1):

The scales package has a nice function called percent, where you can easily change several parameters, like accuracy.

```
mt.per %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric),~./100  )) %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric),scales::percent, accuracy = 1))
```